# Phonegap: Use javascript in java

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I'm building an android app using Phonegap.
It uses a Bluetooth connection to send data to a WIN CE pc.

When I want to increase or decrease a value of a variable on my tablet, the javascript that is used to control the GUI uses java to send a message to increase or decrease the variable on the WIN CE pc.

When the WIN CE pc receives a up or down message it changes the variable and sends the current value back to the tablet.

I receive the message correctly on my tablet in the Java part of the app.
Now I want to be able to control received message and see what value has changed ( there are multiple parameters that can be changed on the tablet) and change the displayed value.

Currently I'm doing by using a phonegap javascript link file (I don't know how to call this) which calls a Java function which just returns the current received value. and this javascript function is called by a timer several times a second. This results in a slow response.

I know it's possible to execute Javascript in java , but is it possible to change a value from a different javascript file doing this? 
If this is possible I could just call a javascript function from my Java to change the value instead of scanning every 100/150 ms to see if any values have changed.

Or is there a different way of doing this?

Thanks in advance and if any code is required I'll be happy to supply it.

Martijn

Comment: By the JavaScript link function your referring to a plugin correct? If so you could store the variables in java and run the update in a java thread reducing the load time on the plugin callback

Comment: Thanks for your reply! By Javascript link file I mean the Javascript that bridges the Webview side With the actual Java plugin. which looks like this: `Bluetooth.prototype.connect = function(successCallback,failureCallback,address,uuid) {
     return exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'Bluetooth', 'connect', [address, uuid]);
 }` And I have the variables already in my Java file because I received them via Bluetooth. But I need this variables to be passed to the Javascript file to alter the displayed parameters or to alter the displayed parameters from the Java side. how can I do this?

Comment: Use custom plugin for that.

Comment: But how can I pass the values to my javascript file? I can send data from Javascript to Java but how can I send Data from Java to Javascript?

Comment: Try looking up "call JavaScript from java phonegap" or get the source files for the phonegap java libray and look at their plugins. I bet you can trace down that very Bluetooth method and either extend it or make a new plugin by copying some code bits

Comment: I've build the Bluetooth plugin I use myself so it won't be hard to find the method ;-) I've found `webView.sendJavascript("test();");` to work, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!